# Envio de Pedido de Produtos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Galera, estou montando um sistema de envio de pedido de produtos, na página de seleção de produtos, temos a seleção deles, onde cada um vai ter um `input`, porém, indeterminados, como faço para enviar todos esse `inputs` para a base, independente da quantidade?

**PHP**

```
$produtos = $_POST['produto_solicitado'];      
foreach($_POST['quantidade'] as $indice => $quanti){
    $produtos_selecionado=$produtos[$indice];
}
$usuario_bd = 'root';
$senha_bd   = '';
$host_db    = 'localhost';
$base_dados_pedidos = 'psaude_pedidos_' . $chns_cliente;
$charset_db = 'utf8';
$conexao_pdo = null;
$detalhes_pdo_pedidos  = 'mysql:host=' . $host_db;
$detalhes_pdo_pedidos .= ';dbname='. $base_dados_pedidos;
$detalhes_pdo_pedidos .= ';charset='. $charset_db;
try {
    $conexao_pdo_pedidos = new PDO($detalhes_pdo_pedidos, $usuario_bd, $senha_bd);
} catch (PDOException $e_pedidos) {
    print "Erro: " . $e_pedidos->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$username_table = 'pedido_' . $chns_cliente . '_' . $PedidoID;
$prepara_table = $conexao_pdo_pedidos->prepare("CREATE TABLE $username_table (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `produto` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_org` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_desc` longtext NOT NULL, `quantidade` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_total_prod` longtext NOT NULL, `obs` longtext NOT NULL, `data_pedido` longtext NOT NULL, `chns` longtext NOT NULL, `para` longtext NOT NULL, `quem` longtext NOT NULL, `pedido` longtext NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))");
$prepara_table_autoinc = $conexao_pdo_pedidos->prepare("ALTER TABLE $username_table MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
$prepara = $conexao_pdo_pedidos->prepare("INSERT INTO $username_table (`produto`,`valor_org`,`valor_desc`,`valor_total_prod`,`quantidade`,`obs`,`data_pedido`,`chns`,`para`,`quem`,`pedidoID`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$verifica_table = $prepara_table->execute();
$verifica_table_autoinc = $prepara_table_autoinc->execute();
$verifica = $prepara->execute(  
   array(
          $produtos_selecionado,
          $valor_org,
          $valor_desc,
          $valor_total_prod,
          $quantidade,
          $obs,
          $data_pedido,
          $chns,
          $para,
          $quem,
          $pedidoID
    )
);
if ( $verifica ) {
    echo "Pedido Enviado";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?echo$endereco;?>assets/inc/envia/pedido" class="form_planeta" id='form_planeta' method="post">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" name="empresa">
    <input name="produto_solicitado[]" value="787879" class="hide">
    <input name="quantidade[]" value="12" class="">
    <input name="produto_solicitado[]" value="7878798" class="hide">
    <input name="quantidade[]" value="1" class="">
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect site envia_again">
    <p class="wht">Cadastrar Pedido</p></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Coloque o que vc tem feito. Qual o problema e o que vc quer. Dessa forma sua pergunta provavelmente vai ser fechada.

Comment: Esses `inputs` são do tipo `checkbox`? Você está tentando fazer isso através de um `form` com `submit` ou com javascript?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, eu estou tendo um problema com a conversão do array quando vai fazer o `insert`, a mensagem é  "Array to string conversion". `$produtos = $_POST['produto_solicitado'];      
foreach($_POST['produto_solicitado'] as $indice => $valor){
    $produtos_selecionado=$produtos[$indice];
}`

Comment: Eu estou usando PDO com a inclusão em array(); `$verifica = $prepara->execute(
 array(
  $produtos_selecionado
 )
)`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, eu mudei para a inserção com o mysql como no link que você mandou, porém só está sendo incluso um produto, os demais ele ignora. A `name` dos `input` estão com as `[]`, mas mesmo assim ignora.

Comment: Sem código postado fica difícil analisar a dificuldade. Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, eu adicionei o código na pergunta.

Comment: Acho que entendi errado, como são seus inputs?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[]" value="7878798">`

Comment: Não é a solução do problema mas sua declaração INSERT tem duas correções a fazer: a coluna criada no banco é `pedido` e não `pedidoID` conforme está na declaração INSERT, Número de parâmetro inválido: o número de variáveis vinculadas não corresponde, falta um `?` No mais, resta saber a estrutura HTML do formulario para entender como são passados os dados.

Comment: Eu fiz as correções e deu certo, só fiz outro `foreach` para a `quantidade[]` para inibir a conversão que não estava sendo feita do `array`. Porém continua sendo adicionado somente um input. Eu atualizei a pergunta com o código html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já havia desenvolvido um sistema baseado nas informações que estavam na sua pergunta antes de você editá-la, porém, acho que você pode aproveitar a minha resposta - ( principalmente no que está comentado com `// prepare e bind` e `// definir parâmetros e executar` que são os pontos chaves) - e adaptar a sua necessidade.

> Com a sua conexão, comigo não funcionou, por isso mudei no exemplo

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['produto_solicitado'])){

    $PedidoID= ($_POST['pedido']);
    $array = ($_POST['produto_solicitado']);
    $quant=count($array);
    $chns_cliente="leo";

    // conexão
    $hostname="localhost";  
    $username="USUARIO";  
    $password="SENHA";  
    $db = "NOME_DB"; 

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

    // Checa conexão
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Conexão falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $username_table = 'pedido_' . $chns_cliente . '_' . $PedidoID;
    $prepara_table = $conn->prepare("CREATE TABLE $username_table (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `produto` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_org` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_desc` longtext NOT NULL, `quantidade` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_total_prod` longtext NOT NULL, `obs` longtext NOT NULL, `data_pedido` longtext NOT NULL, `chns` longtext NOT NULL, `para` longtext NOT NULL, `quem` longtext NOT NULL, `pedido` longtext NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))");
    $prepara_table_autoinc = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE $username_table MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");

    $verifica_table = $prepara_table->execute();
    $verifica_table_autoinc = $prepara_table_autoinc->execute();


    // prepare e bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $username_table (produto,valor_org,valor_desc,valor_total_prod,quantidade,obs,data_pedido,chns,para,quem,pedido) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $produto, $valor_org, $valor_desc, $valor_total_prod, $quantidade, $obs, $data_pedido, $chns, $para, $quem, $pedido);

    // definir parâmetros e executar
    for ( $a=0; $a<$quant; $a++ ) {
        $check = $array[$a]['quantidade'];
        if($check!=""){
            $produto = $array[$a]['produto'];
            $valor_org = $array[$a]['valor_org'];
            $valor_desc = $array[$a]['valor_desc'];
            $valor_total_prod = $array[$a]['valor_total_prod'];
            $quantidade = $array[$a]['quantidade'];
            $obs = $array[$a]['obs'];
            $data_pedido = $array[$a]['data_pedido'];
            $chns = $array[$a]['chns'];
            $para = $array[$a]['para'];
            $quem = $array[$a]['quem'];
            $pedido = $array[$a]['pedido'];
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}

$PedidoID=rand(5, 150000);
```

**Biblioteca e script** (opcional)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
        var v3 ="";
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        var replaceD = currentVal.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
        $(this).val(replaceD);
        var v1 = Number($(this).prev().prev().val());
        var v2 = Number($(this).val());
        v3 = ($(this).prev().val());
        v3 = Number(v3.substring(0, v3.length - 1));
        var calculatedval = parseFloat((v1-(v3*(v1/100))) * v2).toFixed(2);
        $(this).next().val(calculatedval);
   });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

<!-- numero pedido -->
<input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="<?php echo $PedidoID; ?>" />

<!-- produto 1 -->
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][produto]" value="7878797" />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" value="100.00" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_desc]" value="5%" placeholder="valor_desc" readonly />
<input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" value="" placeholder="quantidade"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" value="" placeholder="valor_total_prod" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][obs]" value="" placeholder="obs"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][data_pedido]" value="" placeholder="data_pedido"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][chns]" value="" placeholder="chns"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][para]" value="" placeholder="para"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][quem]" value="" placeholder="quem"/>
<input type="hidden" name="produto_solicitado[0][pedido]" value="<?php echo $PedidoID; ?>" />

<br>
<!-- produto 2 -->
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][produto]" value="7878798" />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" value="150.00" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_desc]" value="5%" placeholder="valor_desc" readonly />
<input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" value="" placeholder="quantidade"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" value="" placeholder="valor_total_prod" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][obs]" value="" placeholder="obs"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][data_pedido]" value="" placeholder="data_pedido"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][chns]" value="" placeholder="chns"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][para]" value="" placeholder="para"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][quem]" value="" placeholder="quem"/>
<input type="hidden" name="produto_solicitado[1][pedido]" value="<?php echo $PedidoID; ?>" />

<br>
<!-- produto 3 -->
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][produto]" value="7878799" />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][valor_org]" value="200.00" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][valor_desc]" value="5%" placeholder="valor_desc" readonly />
<input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[2][quantidade]" value="" placeholder="quantidade"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][valor_total_prod]" value="" placeholder="valor_total_prod" readonly />
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][obs]" value="" placeholder="obs"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][data_pedido]" value="" placeholder="data_pedido"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][chns]" value="" placeholder="chns"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][para]" value="" placeholder="para"/>
<input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[2][quem]" value="" placeholder="quem"/>
<input type="hidden" name="produto_solicitado[2][pedido]" value="<?php echo $PedidoID; ?>" />


<button type="submit" class="waves-effect site envia_again">
    <p class="wht">Cadastrar Pedido</p></button>
</form>
```

> Se o usuário der refresh o pedido será inserido novamente na mesma tabela.
>   Para evitar isso faça um `select` e se não houver retorno, ou seja -  `if(empty($result))`, prossiga com os próximos passos para inserir no banco de dados:

```
...............
...............

$username_table = 'pedido_' . $chns_cliente . '_' . $PedidoID;

$query = "SELECT pedido FROM $username_table";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(empty($result)) {

$prepara_table = $conn->prepare("CREATE TABLE $username_table (`id` int(11) NOT NULL, `produto` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_org` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_desc` longtext NOT NULL, `quantidade` longtext NOT NULL, `valor_total_prod` longtext NOT NULL, `obs` longtext NOT NULL, `data_pedido` longtext NOT NULL, `chns` longtext NOT NULL, `para` longtext NOT NULL, `quem` longtext NOT NULL, `pedido` longtext NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id))");
$prepara_table_autoinc = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE $username_table MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");

$verifica_table = $prepara_table->execute();
$verifica_table_autoinc = $prepara_table_autoinc->execute();

// prepare e bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $username_table (produto,valor_org,valor_desc,valor_total_prod,quantidade,obs,data_pedido,chns,para,quem,pedido) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $produto, $valor_org, $valor_desc, $valor_total_prod, $quantidade, $obs, $data_pedido, $chns, $para, $quem, $pedido);

// definir parâmetros e executar
for ( $a=0; $a<$quant; $a++ ) {
    $check = $array[$a]['quantidade'];
    if($check!=""){
        $produto = $array[$a]['produto'];
        $valor_org = $array[$a]['valor_org'];
        $valor_desc = $array[$a]['valor_desc'];
        $valor_total_prod = $array[$a]['valor_total_prod'];
        $quantidade = $array[$a]['quantidade'];
        $obs = $array[$a]['obs'];
        $data_pedido = $array[$a]['data_pedido'];
        $chns = $array[$a]['chns'];
        $para = $array[$a]['para'];
        $quem = $array[$a]['quem'];
        $pedido = $array[$a]['pedido'];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$stmt->close();

}else{
    echo "tabela já existe";
}
..............
..............
```

> Se optar por não usar jquery, retire dos inputs `readonly`

Comment: Cara, você me salvou. Mas só mais uma pergunta, o cliente irá selecionar os produtos desejados, e isso vai jogando meio que no carrinho com ajax, como os `inputs` estão já pré-definidos por [1], [2]... tem como quando ele selecionar, essa numeração ser gerada automaticamente, por ordem de adição? Eu tentei fazer pra pegar pela `id` do produto na DB mas não deu certo pela ordem dos offset.

Comment: @ThomasFranklin, só montando o cenário e fazendo testes.